# How to create a table with columns from other 4 tables(they don't have primary/foreign key relations)?

Tags: mysql

how can I create a SQL statement to create a table that has columns from 4 tables? So in my new created table I would like to extract the Id, Product Title, Items in cart(number) (from these 4 tables so it will be 4 columns with Items in cart (number)), Link. These tables have 3024 rows so how can I extract these information in one table?
I attached the tables(SQL) and the table(SQL) that I would like to have(I would like a SQL command to do that an insert or join). I will appreciate any help.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `csv_10_05`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csv_10_05` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product title` varchar(2040) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product price` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `items in cart` varchar(2020) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items in cart(number)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(2024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `csv_11_05`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csv_11_05` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product title` varchar(2040) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product price` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `items in cart` varchar(2020) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items in cart(number)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(2024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `csv_12_05`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csv_12_05` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product title` varchar(2040) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product price` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `items in cart` varchar(2020) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items in cart(number)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(2024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `csv_13_05`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csv_13_05` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product title` varchar(2040) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product price` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `items in cart` varchar(2020) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items in cart(number)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(2024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this is what I want (now I've created manually but I would like a query like join to extract the columns)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `amazon_stock`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amazon_stock` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product title` varchar(2040) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `items in cart(10_05)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items in cart(11_05)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items in cart(12_05)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items in cart(13_05)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(2024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Are you only going to be selecting data and not inserting? Your final table might be better suited to a view.

Comment: I think is better an INSERT statement

Comment: One table per month?  Not wise.  No indexes?  Not wise.

Comment: To continue Rick's list, space in identifiers, MyISAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a table with an extra column to distinguish where it came from
2. Do something like

...

```
INSERT INTO new_table (title, price, items_ct, link, which)
    ( SELECT *, '10_05' AS which FROM csv_10_05 )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT *, '11_05' AS which FROM csv_11_05 )
    UNION ALL
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I can't give you a vote because i don't have enough reputation but i marked as a correct answer